# Create a transposed one-row dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe of the form

```
                   name     product_name    current_page
DATI_BENE          NaN      NaN             4.0
DATI_PERSONALI     NaN      NaN             4.0
HOMEPAGE           NaN      NaN             4.0
Next_Command       4.0      NaN             NaN
Start_Procedure    8.0      NaN             NaN
Valore_Auto        NaN      12.0            NaN
```

Out of it, I would like to make a new one with only one row ignoring the NaNs, like

```
DATI_BENE   DATI_PERSONALI  HOMEPAGE    Next_Command    Start_Procedure     Valore_Auto
4.0         4.0             4.0         4.0             8.0                 12.0
```

Is there an uncomplicate way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try;

```
df.stack().to_frame().droplevel(1).T
#or df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1].rename(None).to_frame().T
```

---

```
   DATI_BENE  DATI_PERSONALI  HOMEPAGE  Next_Command  Start_Procedure  \
0        4.0             4.0       4.0           4.0              8.0   

   Valore_Auto  
0         12.0
```